# Why doesn't for loop run through all my readlines?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to get it to run through more than 3 lines of text but the two I have now don't even work properly.

The textfile is

```
74,85,65,56
97,67,83,96
```

Here is the code I've been working on

```
file = open('grades.txt','r')
for x in file:
    read = file.readline()
    sep = read.split(",")
def toNumbers():
    changeNum = [eval(x) for x in sep]
    return changeNum 
def sumlist():
    total = 0
    sum(pls)
    average = sum(pls)/len(sep)
    print ("Your average is: ", average)
def main():
     sumlist()
pls = toNumbers()
main()
```

Output should be

```
Your average is: 70.0
Your average is: 85.75
```

What I'm getting is only this

```
Your average is: 85.75
```

When I add in a third line in my textfile I get this error

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

The third line is also just a row of numbers in the text file and can continue from there

```
74,85,65,56
97,67,83,96
10,20,30,40
```

Output should be

```
Your average is: 70.0
Your average is: 85.75
Your average is: 25.0
```

Comment: please state what the third line is.

Comment: Looks like you are overwriting `sep` with every loop.

Comment: @EamonnKenny I edited my post for you it's just another row of numbers.

Comment: @AlexPshenko, this is part of the problem. See my answer.

Comment: I know this sounds like a slightly inpolite comment, but have you coded before or are you learning? You should never add code outside of function structures if you are using functions. The main call should be in main as you did, but the iterator should be logically thought out and not be outside all the functions. That is why you are getting into such hot water here.

Comment: @EamonnKenny No worries I'm learning so I'm trying to understand everything. I don't mind the harsh comments if that is one! You're helping me and I appreciate that. But I should have had the file open in it's own function is what you're trying to tell me?

Comment: not meant to be harsh. I did exactly the same thing when starting so you are just doing what everyone else does. I'm just giving you a hint to avoid this type of issue in the future. If you generate a list from a file make sure the list is fully self contained and passed to the next function. Don't try reading stuff outside of a function. That's all I'm saying. The reply from DavidG does just this and that why his code is clean and easy to understand.

Comment: @EamonnKenny yeah I get that. Makes a lot of sense once I took a look at it thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would remove your `main` function as it isn't really needed in your example and call `toNumbers` and `sumlist` in the for loop itself. Note that you will need to pass the variables as arguments for the function:

```
def toNumbers(sep):
    changeNum = [int(x) for x in sep]
    return changeNum

def sumlist(pls,sep):
    average = sum(pls)/len(sep)
    print ("Your average is: ", average)


file = open('grades.txt','r')

lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    sep = line.split(",")

    pls = toNumbers(sep)
    sumlist(pls,sep)
```

This gives:

```
Your average is:  70.0
Your average is:  85.75
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This looks a lot more simple than what I had going on. I was looking at a bunch of examples for reference and thought they were things that I needed such as `main` if I was using functions. I wasn't too far off though huh?

Comment: @kengu No problem :) Python is a language that values code readability. Therefore, (in general) the easier it is to read your code, the better it is. Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if this solves your problem.

Comment: [This](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) might also be useful :)

Comment: I'll keep this in mind from now on lol, thanks again. Also I'd totally upvote you all if I could, I actually just made this account because I was so fed up with coding... But I will once my rep goes up if I can by then!

Answer (score 3):

This is simple.

```
for x in file:
```

already iterates over lines of your file, but you are ignoring the value of `x` which is the content of the first line. You simply grab the content of the second line with your:

```
 read = file.readline()
```

Adding another line causes error, because what you told Python to do is `for each line in the file, read next line`, so `for` loop takes every odd line into `x` and then every even line is stored in `read`. Therefore only files with even number of lines are processed without error.
You want to have this:

```
for read in file:
    sep = read.split(",")
```

**EDIT:** Complete example:

```
def toNumbers(sep):
    changeNum = [float(x) for x in sep]
    return changeNum

def sumlist(sep):
    total = 0
    sum(pls)
    average = sum(pls)/len(sep)
    print ("Your average is: ", average)

def main():
    file = open('grades.txt','r')
    for read in file:
        sep = read.split(",")
        sep = toNumbers(sep)
        sumlist(sep)

main()
```

Comment: I'm only getting an output of Your average is: 85.75 still.

Comment: @kengu see complete example - you are overwriting content of `sep` all the time. And never ever use `eval` on any input - it can execute arbitrary code.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with `sep` would it be simpler to assign everything at once? If you can do that, but I'll watch out for `eval` next time, thanks!

Comment: @kengu in every iteration of `for` loop, variable `sep` gets a new value from freshly read line, so the former line is forgotten.

Comment: That's why it was only printing the second line then. So you separated everything in it's own function to avoid them assigning the new values to each other?

Answer (score 1):

The code you have above doesn't even run for me in python 3. However changing the readline to readlines as below did work perfectly.

```
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    sep = line.split(",")
```

Comment: This is what I'm getting now                                                                                    `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`I tried before splitting readlines but it wouldn't work for me for some reason

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you use `file` on `for` loop and you use `file.readline()` on each step. That's why when you have 3 lines it shows error. Try add another line, 4 lines, and it will show the last line.

Printing your `read` and `sep` would help you.
You'll notice using your code, you'll only get the latest line because of `sep` assignment.

This code below would achieve what you want:

```
file = open('sample.txt','r')

raw_lines = file.readlines()
lines = [raw_line.strip() for raw_line in raw_lines]


def show_avg_per_line(line):
    line_list = list(map(int, line.split(",")))
    average = sum(line_list) / len(line_list)
    print("Your average is: ", average)

for line in lines:
    show_avg_per_line(line)
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, never went to a fourth line because I was so frustrated with the first two! And I was printing out my inputs to see where they were but that was only confusing me more. Thank you though!